# Get Parent Modified API names when child record update using apex or trigger

Tags: apex, trigger

We have Case (Parent Object) and Case Service (child Object). There are 100 fields in case.
If i updated 20 fields on case record, i want know api names of updated 20 fields not on the immediate update of case. It will be on the case service record update.

Answer (score 1):

I hope that I understood your question correctly.

How to retain history of the changed fields:
Because you probably want track up to 100 fields you cannot use Field History Tracking.

Easiest way to do this is to create trigger that will compare record before and after change by iterating over all of the fields, build a string that will be concatenation of the API names and save it to custom field on that case. Later you can fetch that field when update of the Case Service.

If you want to retain history of more than 1 update you'll need for example create custom object that will have master detail relationship to the case and on update of the case custom object will be created with the list of changed fields.

Comment: Can you please send me trigger

Comment: In this community we're not doing your work for you. If you have problems with specific part of your solution, please provide parts of the code which are failing and we will help you.